# Can't all-caps the chapter number string

Tags: memoir, fmtcount

My MWE generates "One" for the chapter number. I want the "One" to be "ONE". I tried everything I could think of including `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\MakeUppercase{\Numberstring{chapter}}}` and `{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter}}` but nothing is working for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\huge\filcenter}
    {\thechapter}
    {1em}
    {\Huge #1}
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{}
    {\thesubsubsection}
    {}
    {#1}

\let\ordinal\relax
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
This is some text in the first chapter.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly related to expansion. I have seen references to requiring `\expandafter` twice, as in `\expandafter\MakeUppercase{\expandafter\SomeMacro}` but it did not work for me. What happens if you try `\MakeUppercase{One}` ? That will resolve whether the problem is related to expansion, or `MakeUppercase` itself.

Comment: You wrote, "I tried everything I could think of...". Did that include reading the user guide of the [fmtcount](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) package? :-)

Comment: @Mico I observe that the MWE does not load `fmtcount`. So why would the OP look at that package documentation?

Comment: @Mico Actually, I was missing something. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fmtcount](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) package provides a macro called `\NUMBERstring`. You should be using this macro instead of `\Numberstring` to generate the all-uppercase string "ONE".

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\arabic{chapter} \numberstring{chapter} \Numberstring{chapter} \NUMBERstring{chapter}
\end{document}
```